# how to find out how much power my external hard drive is using?

Tags: hardware

I want to monitor the power usage when plugged into my laptop (specifically voltage and current) of my hard drive during various activities. How do I find out if I am on Linux?

(right now I am using Ubuntu 15.04, if needed)

Comment: Well, if it's plugged into the wall separately, you could always just use a wall power-usage monitor....

Comment: @TomHunt well thanks I want to know when plugged into laptop

Comment: Is the drive actually powered solely from the laptop? That would be surprising to me; I wouldn't expect USB to be able to provide enough draw. Anyway, after checking a bit I can't find any way to get current power draw, either through the drive end or through USB.

Comment: What connectivity does the hard drive use (USB2, USB3, eSATA, Firewire, …)? Is it entirely powered from the computer? Voltage is fixed by the connection standard, by the way, current is the one that varies according to the drawn power.

Comment: @TomHunt USB2 can power a typical 2½" hard drive.

Comment: @Gilles actually I am doing this because I want to use that hard drive on raspberry pi

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any software utilities, but there are hardware solutions (like [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B013FANC9W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013FANC9W)) that work similar to the solution Tom Hunt suggested for wall power.